# How to run the multigeneblast software

Tags: command-line, software-center

I was trying to install a Bioinformatics related software i.e Multigeneblast.
I have downloaded and untar the tar.gz file in the /home/hiya(in home directory). Now according to the documentation of the tool to run the software we only need to run the command mgb_gui or multigeneblast. But when I have tried it that's giving some font error.(screenshot included).
Then I have tried to install Fontconfig-2.13.1 package.I followed every step like untarring the tar.bz2 and then following commands

```
rm -f src/fcobjshash.h ./configure --prefix=/usr        \
            --sysconfdir=/etc    \
            --localstatedir=/var \
            --disable-docs       \
            --docdir=/usr/share/doc/fontconfig-2.13.1 && make
```

then its giving a configure error.(ScreenShot2)
And after giving 
make install command
its showing

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

what Should I do to solve it.Please let me know.[Configur_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUksY.png)[Multigeneblast Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg291.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output. It's preferable to copy/paste the relevant **text**. See https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is quite right up to some extent. but in some of the case we need to put that. I have just posted the relevant part.

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu.  Fontconfig-2.13.1 is included in the standard repositories of Ubuntu.  There is no reason to compile it manually. Also, if I am not mistaken, your error message does not imply that fontconfig is not installed.

Comment: Thanks Bruni. But I think you haven't looked that while running the multigeneblast software its giving fontconfig error and warning. To solve it I searched on the net and then it suggested to install and update the fontconfigure software.

Comment: Why are you deleting those files? What is the first command supposed to do? `rm -f src/fcobjshash.h ./configure --prefix=...` will delete the files `src/fcobjshash.h` and `./configure`. Is this what you actually ran or did you maybe run `rm -f src/fcobjshash.h; ./configure ...`?

Comment: It was included in the documentation that is given to install the font configure package.http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/fontconfig.html. You can check it here in this link. @terdon

Comment: Yes, as I thought. The instructions tell you to run `rm -f src/fcobjshash.h` first and _then_ run `./configure --prefix=`. You are running them together so you deleted the `./configure` script.

Comment: What configure error are you seeing? Please copy the text of the error into your question and use he [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.